# Saving and accessing field from a custom struct

Tags: c

I defined a struct like this (and other fields but they are not relevant with the question)

```
typedef struct {

  struct sockaddr_in addr_destination;

}MY_PACKET;
```

The main call a function send_command

```
struct sockaddr_in *addr_server;
socklen_t addr_server_lenght;
MY_PACKET command_packet;

void send_command(char *comm, int socket_file_descriptor, struct sockaddr_in *server_address) {
    addr_server = server_address;
    addr_server_lenght = sizeof(*addr_server);
    printf("Server address: %s\n", inet_ntoa(addr_server->sin_addr));

    command_packet.addr_destination = *addr_server;
    printf("Server address: %s\n", inet_ntoa(command_packet.addr_destination.sin_addr));
}
```

so the first printf prints "127.0.0.1" correctly 
the second prints "0.0.0.0"
The rest of the program consists on a thread that send this packet to a server and wait for ack (so i must be able to access all the fields of command_packet from the thread function), but I'm stuck saving the server address in the packet correctly, what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Did you try using a debugger and set break point in your `send_command`?

Comment: I tryed after you told me but after I finally managed to run the debugger i still can't find the source of the mess. Also, how can i read global variables in the debugger? I read values only for local ones.The I run the program again and now the first printf prints 0.0.0.0 too...

Comment: Okay. In that case I think that global variable is being changed in another thread. Put breakpoints at all places whereever you change it.

Comment: I think I'll start again with a different approach, thanks for your help.